# Disable PHPStorm's built-in inspection of JavaScript semicolons

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, code-inspection

PHPStorm 8.0.3 for Mac wants to tell me about missing semicolons in my JavaScript. I don't want PHPStorm to do this.

[This blog page](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/08/code-quality-analysis-in-webstorm/) says...

> Built-in inspections help you detect errors and potential problems,
>   from obvious ones like a missing semicolon ...

Later, the blog indicates that "The full list of built-in inspections is available in Preferences | Inspections", but I can find no mention of semicolons in any of the subcategories of the 14 inspection categories.

Is PHPStorm intransigent about semicolons?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Whenever you want to adjust or disable an inspection, simply put your cursor on the warning and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will open a popup with some suggestions, containing a menu item for available inspections. In your case, the inspection is called `Unterminated statement` and can be found under `JavaScript > Code style issues > Unterminated statement`. You can select `Disable inspection` from the popup submenu to disable it without ever opening the settings dialog. You can also select `Edit inspection profile setting` to open the settings dialog at the right place.

[image]