# PhpStorm type-hint warning for a factory method that returns a descendant class

Tags: phpstorm

In a legacy project with the data mapper pattern we have the following (excerpt):

```
/**
 * @param string $someSearchTerms
 * @return User[]|null
 */
public function getModelsFor($someSearchTerms) 
{
    // snip

    return $this->factory($results);
}
```

The above method is typehinted `@return User[]` where User is a descendant of an abstract `Model` class.

The `factory` method is defined in the abstract mapper and is typehinted as:

```
@return Model[]|null
```

Prior to PhpStorm 2016.2 this wasn't highlighted as an issue - it is now, because it is detecting that the return values don't match, although they do in a sense as User is a concrete implementation of Model.

How do I get rid of this warning?

Comment: This answer explains how to disable inspections on the fly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30383690/1116549

Comment: Try 2016.2.1 EAP build -- maybe it's better there. Other than that -- suppress inspection for that line only as suggested earlier.

Comment: There's somewhere between a couple of hundred and a few hundred of these calls... not really practical to individually suppress the warnings.